# Terraform: Multiple ACM certificates

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform0.11

I'm trying to write some TF that, given a single FQDN for a site, will generate an ACM certificate, create the R53 records for validation and run the validation in a single TF pass.

I'm not using subdomains, and I got it working for a single FQDN, but as is the nature with TF, I want to be able to add another FQDN to the variable in the future to have multiple certs.

When I run the below code I get the error:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
    * aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert: 2 errors occurred:
    * aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert[0]: Resource 'aws_route53_record.cert_validation' does not have attribute 'fqdn' for variable 'aws_route53_record.cert_validation.*.fqdn'
    * aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert[1]: Resource 'aws_route53_record.cert_validation' does not have attribute 'fqdn' for variable 'aws_route53_record.cert_validation.*.fqdn'
```

But I know that the R53 record does export the fqdn attribute.

acm.tf:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  count = "${length(var.certificate_fqdns)}"
  domain_name               = "${element(var.certificate_fqdns, count.index)}"
  validation_method         = "DNS"

  tags = "${local.all_tags}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
    count = "${length(var.certificate_fqdns)}"

    name = "${lookup(local.domain_validation_options[count.index], "resource_record_name")}"
    type = "${lookup(local.domain_validation_options[count.index], "resource_record_type")}"
    zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.cert_fqdn_zone.*.id}"
    records = ["${lookup(local.domain_validation_options[count.index], "resource_record_value")}"]
    ttl = 60
}
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  count                   = "${length(var.certificate_fqdns)}"
  certificate_arn         = "${element(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.arn, count.index)}"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["${aws_route53_record.cert_validation.*.fqdn}"]
}
```

variables.tf:

```
    variable "certificate_fqdns" { 
      description = "The FQDNs to be used to create ACM certificates."
      type        = "list"
      default     = []
    }

    locals {
      domain_validation_options = "${flatten(aws_acm_certificate.cert.*.domain_validation_options)}"
    }

data "aws_route53_zone" "cert_fqdn_zone" {
  name = "${element(var.certificate_fqdns, count.index)}"
}
```

and my vars file contains an entry like this:

```
"certificate_fqdns": [
    "example.com"
]
```

EDIT: Added the data lookup for the Route53 Zones, which only seems to return the zone for the first domain provided in the variable even when there are multiple, different domains. i.e. example1.com and example2.com it will use the same zone ID for both sets of R53 records which will obviously fail

Comment: What Terraform version are you using?

Comment: 11.14, we haven't made the jump to 12 yet